# Filezilla High CPU Usage

Tags: cpu-load, filezilla

My Filezilla takes about 80% of CPU whenever its window is visible. When I minimize the window, CPU usage goes go back down to the expected, low percentage.
I've tried a few versions of filezilla from v3.3 to 3.4, but there it has no effect.

Can anyone suggest some fixes for this problem?
I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug last month with the exact same title. Found it again: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/filezilla/+bug/738430
Description:

```
Binary package hint: filezilla
The CPU usage is very high (50% on a Quad Core CPU) 
and it leaks memory by time (700MB after 1 day of running).
```

Is related to this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wxwidgets2.8/+bug/722375

```
High CPU usage of wxWidget apps caused by dbusmenu
```

If that is your problem too then these these posts are noteworthy:

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wxwidgets2.8/+bug/722375/comments/9
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wxwidgets2.8/+bug/722375/comments/19
```

And looking at all the different links I even end up at the program and line that seems to be the culprit: http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxWidgets/branches/WX_2_8_BRANCH/src/gtk/frame.cpp?r1=66344&r2=67149

I might be totally wrong though :+

Comment: Thank you for reply.

As mentioned in that comment 

`This bug was fixed in the package wxwidgets2.8 - 2.8.11.0-0ubuntu8`

But i have same version in system, so looks like they not fully fixed this problem. This version of package present in current ubuntu repository. Interesting will upgrading to 11.04 solve this issue or not.

Comment: Looks like it is fixed in 11.04. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wxwidgets2.8/+bug/722375: Changed in wxwidgets2.8 (Ubuntu Natty): status:  In Progress → Fix Released